# Primitive stack-based code interpreter

Tags: performance, haskell, interpreter

I've written an interpreter for a simple assembly-like language and it's performing slower than I would like.

It's split into 3 files: the Parser that converts the source to a vector of ints, the VM that actually runs the bytecode, and Tests that has a bubble sort written in the language.

It sorts 100 numbers in about 6 seconds in GHCi. The profiler doesn't tell me much except that the most time is spent inside the step function as it's expected.

The Parser file isn't that needed because it's only run once so it doesn't affect performance.

Another thing to note is that it takes around 250 000 ticks (instructions executed) to do it so I'm pretty sure it could be much faster than 6 seconds.

Is there anything obvious that I could improve?

**Parser**

```
module Parser where

import Data.Vector (Vector, fromList)
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Data.List (sort)

type ByteCode = [Int]

data OpCode = Push | Pop | Add | Sub | Mult | Div | Store | Load | Jmp | Cmp | Not | Br | Dup | Inc | Dec | Swp
    deriving (Enum, Read, Show, Ord, Eq)

arity :: Vector Int
arity = (fromList . map snd . sort) $ zip [Push, Store, Load] [1, 1..] ++ zip [Pop, Add, Sub, Mult, Div] [0, 0..]

charIsNumeric :: Char -> Bool
charIsNumeric c = '0' <= c && '9' >= c

stringIsNumeric :: String -> Bool
stringIsNumeric ('-' : s) = all charIsNumeric s
stringIsNumeric s = all charIsNumeric s

capitalize :: String -> String
capitalize [] = []
capitalize (x : xs) = toUpper x : xs

wordToByteCode :: String -> Int
wordToByteCode str = if stringIsNumeric str then read str else fromEnum opCodeEnum
    where
        opCodeEnum :: OpCode
        opCodeEnum = read $ capitalize str

stringToByteCode :: String -> ByteCode
stringToByteCode = map wordToByteCode . words

sourceToByteCode :: String -> ByteCode
sourceToByteCode = map wordToByteCode . concatMap words . lines
```

**VM**

```
module VM where

import Parser (ByteCode, OpCode(..), arity)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import Data.List (intercalate)
import Utility

data VM = VM {
    byteCode :: Vector Int,
    programCounter :: Int,
    stack :: [Int],
    memory :: IM.IntMap Int
    }
    deriving (Show)

fromCode :: ByteCode -> VM
fromCode code = VM { byteCode = Vector.fromList code, programCounter = 0, stack = [], memory = IM.empty }

step :: VM -> VM
step vm = next
    where
        bc = byteCode vm
        pc = programCounter vm
        st = stack vm
        mm = memory vm
        inst = toEnum $ bc ! pc
        pop1 = tail st
        pop2 = tail pop1
        top1 = head st
        top2 = head pop1
        nextPc = pc + 1
        next = case inst of
            Pop -> vm { stack = pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Push -> vm { stack = bc ! nextPc : st, programCounter = pc + 2 }
            Add -> vm { stack = (top1 + top2) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Sub -> vm { stack = (top2 - top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Mult -> vm { stack = (top1 * top2) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Div -> vm { stack = (top2 `div` top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Store -> vm { stack = pop2, programCounter = nextPc, memory = IM.insert top1 top2 mm }
            Load -> vm { stack = mm IM.! top1 : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Jmp -> vm { stack = pop1, programCounter = top1 }
            Cmp -> vm { stack = signum (top2 - top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Not -> vm { stack = (if top1 > 0 then -1 else 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Br -> vm { stack = pop2, programCounter = if top2 > 0 then top1 else nextPc } 
            Dup -> vm { stack = top1 : st, programCounter = nextPc }
            Inc -> vm { stack = (top1 + 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc } 
            Dec -> vm { stack = (top1 - 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Swp -> vm { stack = top2 : top1 : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }

endState :: VM -> Bool
endState vm = programCounter vm == Vector.length (byteCode vm)

run :: VM -> VM
run = until endState step

runCount :: VM -> (Int, VM)
runCount = untilCount endState step

debug :: (VM -> String) -> VM -> (VM, [String])
debug watch vm = if endState vm then (vm, []) else (nextVm, watch vm : logs)
    where
        (nextVm, logs) = debug watch (step vm)

instructionLogger :: VM -> String
instructionLogger vm = show (toEnum $ byteCode vm ! programCounter vm :: OpCode)

watch :: Int -> VM -> String
watch n vm = case IM.lookup n (memory vm) of
    Nothing -> "undefined"
    Just a -> show a

composeLoggers :: [VM -> String] -> VM -> String
composeLoggers loggers vm = (intercalate "  " . map ($ vm)) loggers

printDebug :: (VM -> String) -> VM -> IO ()
printDebug f v = putStr $ unlines $ snd $ debug f v
```

**Tests**

```
module Tests where

import qualified Parser as Parser
import qualified VM as VM
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM

bubble = unlines [
    "push 0", "push 1000", "store",
    "push 0", "push 1001", "store",
    "push 1000", "load", "load",
    "push 1001", "load", "load",
    "cmp",
    "push 38", "br",
    "push 1000", "load", "load",
    "push 1001", "load", "load",
    "push 1000", "load", "store",
    "push 1001", "load", "store",
    "push 1001", "load", "inc", "dup", "push 1001", "store",
    "push 100",
    "cmp", "not",
    "push 10", "br", 
    "push 0", "push 1001", "store",
    "push 1000", "load", "inc", "dup", "push 1000", "store",    
    "push 100",
    "cmp", "not",
    "push 10", "br"
    ]

vm = VM.fromCode $ Parser.sourceToByteCode bubble
vmWithData = vm { VM.memory = IM.fromList $ zip [0..100] [100, 99..0] }

main = print $ VM.run $ vmWithData

dbg = VM.printDebug (VM.composeLoggers [VM.instructionLogger, VM.watch 101, show . VM.programCounter]) vmWithData
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously bad, except that you're benchmarking ghci's interpreter. It's not designed to be efficient. Try compiling with optimizations.

Comment: I did to profile it. It's obviously much faster but it still hangs at around 500, taking around 4 seconds.

Comment: I'll take a closer look, then.

Comment: I can't actually compile and test because the `Utility` module is absent.

Comment: Ok, `Utility` was only used for `untilCount`, which I reimplemented.  Compiled with -O2, this runs basically instantly.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my investigations, I'm going to say that your problem is exactly what I said in the comments: performance testing with ghci.

I modified VM.hs a bit, to get it to build:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module VM where

import Parser (ByteCode, OpCode(..), arity)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import Data.List (intercalate)

data VM = VM {
    byteCode :: Vector Int,
    programCounter :: Int,
    stack :: [Int],
    memory :: IM.IntMap Int
    }
    deriving (Show)

fromCode :: ByteCode -> VM
fromCode code = VM { byteCode = Vector.fromList code, programCounter = 0, stack = [], memory = IM.empty }

step :: VM -> VM
step vm = next
    where
        bc = byteCode vm
        pc = programCounter vm
        st = stack vm
        mm = memory vm
        inst = toEnum $ bc ! pc
        pop1 = tail st
        pop2 = tail pop1
        top1 = head st
        top2 = head pop1
        nextPc = pc + 1
        next = case inst of
            Pop -> vm { stack = pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Push -> vm { stack = bc ! nextPc : st, programCounter = pc + 2 }
            Add -> vm { stack = (top1 + top2) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Sub -> vm { stack = (top2 - top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Mult -> vm { stack = (top1 * top2) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Div -> vm { stack = (top2 `div` top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Store -> vm { stack = pop2, programCounter = nextPc, memory = IM.insert top1 top2 mm }
            Load -> vm { stack = mm IM.! top1 : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Jmp -> vm { stack = pop1, programCounter = top1 }
            Cmp -> vm { stack = signum (top2 - top1) : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }
            Not -> vm { stack = (if top1 > 0 then -1 else 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Br -> vm { stack = pop2, programCounter = if top2 > 0 then top1 else nextPc } 
            Dup -> vm { stack = top1 : st, programCounter = nextPc }
            Inc -> vm { stack = (top1 + 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc } 
            Dec -> vm { stack = (top1 - 1) : pop1, programCounter = nextPc }
            Swp -> vm { stack = top2 : top1 : pop2, programCounter = nextPc }

endState :: VM -> Bool
endState vm = programCounter vm == Vector.length (byteCode vm)

run :: VM -> VM
run = until endState step

runCount :: VM -> (Int, VM)
runCount = untilCount endState step
  where
    untilCount f g = go 0
      where
        go !n x | f x = (n, x)
                | otherwise = go (n + 1) (g x)

debug :: (VM -> String) -> VM -> (VM, [String])
debug watch vm = if endState vm then (vm, []) else (nextVm, watch vm : logs)
    where
        (nextVm, logs) = debug watch (step vm)

instructionLogger :: VM -> String
instructionLogger vm = show (toEnum $ byteCode vm ! programCounter vm :: OpCode)

watch :: Int -> VM -> String
watch n vm = case IM.lookup n (memory vm) of
    Nothing -> "undefined"
    Just a -> show a

composeLoggers :: [VM -> String] -> VM -> String
composeLoggers loggers vm = (intercalate "  " . map ($ vm)) loggers

printDebug :: (VM -> String) -> VM -> IO ()
printDebug f v = putStr $ unlines $ snd $ debug f v
```

My changes were:

1. Enable the `BangPatterns` extension to make it easier to efficiently write `untilCount`
2. Remove the import of `Utility`.
3. Add `untilCount` into `runCount`.

I also changed `Tests` to use `runCount` just to be sure I was getting the same operation count as you.

After those changes, this is a sample session:

```
carl@debian:~/hask/codereview/stackint$ ghc -O2 -main-is Tests Tests.hs 
[1 of 3] Compiling Parser           ( Parser.hs, Parser.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling VM               ( VM.hs, VM.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Tests            ( Tests.hs, Tests.o )
Linking Tests ...
carl@debian:~/hask/codereview/stackint$ time ./Tests 
(267252,VM {byteCode = fromList [0,0,0,1000,6,0,0,0,1001,6,0,1000,7,7,0,1001,7,7,9,0,38,11,0,1000,7,7,0,1001,7,7,0,1000,7,6,0,1001,7,6,0,1001,7,13,12,0,1001,6,0,100,9,10,0,10,11,0,0,0,1001,6,0,1000,7,13,12,0,1000,6,0,100,9,10,0,10,11], programCounter = 73, stack = [], memory = fromList [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10),(11,11),(12,12),(13,13),(14,14),(15,15),(16,16),(17,17),(18,18),(19,19),(20,20),(21,21),(22,22),(23,23),(24,24),(25,25),(26,26),(27,27),(28,28),(29,29),(30,30),(31,31),(32,32),(33,33),(34,34),(35,35),(36,36),(37,37),(38,38),(39,39),(40,40),(41,41),(42,42),(43,43),(44,44),(45,45),(46,46),(47,47),(48,48),(49,49),(50,50),(51,51),(52,52),(53,53),(54,54),(55,55),(56,56),(57,57),(58,58),(59,59),(60,60),(61,61),(62,62),(63,63),(64,64),(65,65),(66,66),(67,67),(68,68),(69,69),(70,70),(71,71),(72,72),(73,73),(74,74),(75,75),(76,76),(77,77),(78,78),(79,79),(80,80),(81,81),(82,82),(83,83),(84,84),(85,85),(86,86),(87,87),(88,88),(89,89),(90,90),(91,91),(92,92),(93,93),(94,94),(95,95),(96,96),(97,97),(98,98),(99,99),(100,100),(1000,101),(1001,0)]})

real    0m0.155s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.116s
```

Nearly everything there is in `sys` time as well, which usually means doing IO. Let me do some proper benchmarking.  Proper benchmarking in haskell involves using the [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package. I added a new file to contain the `criterion` code, `Main.hs`:

```
import Criterion.Main

import qualified VM
import qualified Tests

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [bench "sort" $ whnf (fst . VM.runCount) Tests.vmWithData]
```

As a quick explanation of Criterion in general - benchmarking in a lazy language can be tricky. Criterion provides tools to let you make sure you're doing it right. I used the `whnf` function to benchmark counting the number of steps the program runs. Since it's impossible to determine how many steps it runs without actually running it, that ensures that the benchmarking isn't fooled by laziness. And here's another terminal log:

```
carl@debian:~/hask/codereview/stackint$ ghc -O2 Main.hs 
[3 of 4] Compiling Tests            ( Tests.hs, Tests.o ) [flags changed]
[4 of 4] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
carl@debian:~/hask/codereview/stackint$ ./Main 
warming up
estimating clock resolution...
mean is 21.01945 us (40001 iterations)
found 2284 outliers among 39999 samples (5.7%)
  678 (1.7%) low severe
  1345 (3.4%) high severe
estimating cost of a clock call...
mean is 16.59960 us (6 iterations)

benchmarking sort
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 6.015491 s
mean: 52.26690 ms, lb 50.39930 ms, ub 57.08317 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 14.30133 ms, lb 6.851806 ms, ub 29.74848 ms, ci 0.950
found 7 outliers among 100 samples (7.0%)
  3 (3.0%) high mild
  4 (4.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 96.804%
variance is severely inflated by outliers
```

Criterion gives you a bunch of statistical analysis of its results. It tells me, among other things, that benchmarking in a VirtualBox VM introduces a lot of jitter. That's what all the stuff about variance and outliers is about.  However, if you look at the absolute timings, that doesn't matter too much. Even with the inflated variance, the timing ranges from about 50ms to 57ms. In other words, your code is pretty darn fast already.

But if you're going to benchmark, ***do it properly***.

---

Now, it is possible to improve upon this code a bit. It suffers from some minor excessive laziness.

1. Change the import of `IntMap` to `Data.IntMap.Strict`. This will keep unevaluated expressions from building up in the values in the `IntMap`.
2. Add strictness annotations to the fields that would benefit from it in the `VM` record.

With those two changes, I cut the time spent in the criterion benchmark in half. Here's what I settled on for the definition of `VM`:

```
data VM = VM {
    byteCode :: Vector Int,
    programCounter :: !Int,
    stack :: [Int],
    memory :: !(IM.IntMap Int)
    }
    deriving (Show)
```

Note that this is a valid data definition without any extensions. It's basic haskell that putting a `!` on a field in a data declaration marks that field as strict. More precisely, it means "when the constructor of this type is evaluated, also evaluate this field to whnf".

The `byteCode` field never changes during execution, so it's not necessary to mark it as strict. Once it's evaluated, it stays evaluated. The `stack` field is a recursive data type that is always built directly from constructors. It doesn't help anything to make it strict, it's always already in whnf.

Of the two fields that strictness annotations do help on, I was very surprised that it's actually the `programCounter` field that gets a huge benefit from becoming strict. In retrospect, that's probably because I'm working with GHC 7.8, which automatically unboxes strict "small" fields in data types, and `Int` is small. The auto unboxing significantly reduces the amount of pointer chasing during the loop, so it does make sense that it would improve things.

To get that same improvement on older versions of GHC, you would have to define the data type as:

```
data VM = VM {
    byteCode :: Vector Int,
    programCounter :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Int,
    stack :: [Int],
    memory :: !(IM.IntMap Int)
    }
    deriving (Show)
```

The `UNPACK` pragma indicates to ghc that it should unbox the next field in a data declaration, assuming it is strict. (If it isn't strict, unboxing it would change the semantics, so the pragma is ignored.)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to review my code.